# Can I change the "equal comparator" on LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If I have a list and I do an OrderBy, the elements with empty values `""` go to the top of the ordered list. Instead, I'd like to put them at the bottom of the list. My code:

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(o => o.Field).ToList();
```

is there a way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(o => string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Field))
                      .ThenBy(o => o.Field)
                      .ToList();
```

Because `false` is ordered before `true` this will put all non-empty values first.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how much efficient it is :P, but you can try the following.

```
var orderedList = list.Where(r=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
                      .OrderBy(o => o)
                      .Concat(list.Where(r => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
                      .ToList();
```

You can compare it with `""` or `string.Empty` if you don't want to check for all the white space or null values.

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`? why?

Comment: @defaultlocale, just to check for all types of empty strings , just mentioned that in the answer as well.